# How can I know what are the optional choices for the gem5 command line options such as --cpu-type?

Tags: gem5

There are many possible and optional choices in gem5. For example,I can through the command of `--debug-help` show all the possible debug options for `--debug-flags` assignment. But how can I know the optional choices for `--cpu-type`  assignment  Are there some command like `--cpu-type-help` to show the optional assignment for `--cpu-type`? I ran the command of `gem5.opt help`,I didn't see the introduction about `--cpu-type`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Ciro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64108626/2929155), multiple times there is a command that lists the possible values for the object type without the need to provide a random value. For example, in the case of `--cpu-type`, there is a `--list-cpu-types` that does exactly what you want without requiring an extra (random) argument.

In general, these commands follow the format `--list-x-types`, and their function callbacks are defined at the beginning of the file *configs/common/Options.py* (e.g., for CPU types it is `_listCpuTypes`).

Adding more lists is as easy as adding a respective `ObjectList` (*configs/common/ObjectList.py*) instance for a selected base class. For example, [this patch](https://gem5-review.googlesource.com/c/public/gem5/+/20591/5) ported the previous code for prefetchers to use `ObjectList`.

Comment: Amazing, the error message is so good that I never bothered!

Answer (score 1):

For `--cpu-type`, if you type any wrong value on the CLI e.g.:

```
--cpu-type adsf
```

the error message prints the possible choices:

```
fs.py: error: option --cpu-type: invalid choice: 'asfd' (choose from 'O3_ARM_v7a_3', 'AtomicSimpleCPU', 'TraceCPU', 'ex5_big', 'DerivO3CPU', 'MinorCPU', 'HPI', 'ex5_LITTLE', 'NonCachingSimpleCPU', 'TimingSimpleCPU')
```

This can also be easily seen from the source (configs/common/Options.py) as well:

```
    parser.add_option("--cpu-type", type="choice", default="AtomicSimpleCPU",
                      choices=ObjectList.cpu_list.get_names(),
```

where `cpu_list` is defined as (configs/common/ObjectList.py):

```
cpu_list = CPUList(getattr(m5.objects, 'BaseCPU', None))
```

from which we deduce that valid choices are `BaseCPU` derived classes.

gem5 6bc2111c9674d0c8db22f6a6adcc00e49625aabd.